# Java - how to not print repeats/control the printing of values from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that holds the counts of repetitions of fractions from a file, `1, 2, 3, etc`. I need to print the occurrences of the fractions, but I need to print the fractions only once. The problem I'm running into is that I print every fraction, regardless of the amount of times it is repeated. The code that I have come up with so far is:

```
boolean[] controlsFractionPrinting = new boolean[lengthOfFile];
Arrays.fill(controlsFractionPrinting, true);
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfFile; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfFile; j++) {
        if (count[i] > 1) {
            if (count[i] == count[j])
                controlsFractionPrinting[j] = false;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(controlsFractionPrinting));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
```

The problem with this code is that every count above 1 is "falsed" which would be good but it also "falses" the first occurrence. I need the first occurrence to be true regardless of the count, then any count that is the same is "falsed" after "truing" the first occurrence of the count.

```
count = [3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1]
```

therefore `controlsFractionPrinting` should look something like

```
[true, false, true, true, false, ...].
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The basis of this solution is to store each value that has already been seen into a map so that the map can be queried to see if it already contains a value:

```
boolean[] controlsFractionPrinting = new boolean[lengthOfFile];

// create a map to contain the numbers that have been used
Map<Integer, Object> usedMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfFile; i++) {

    // set the value to false if the usedMap already contains the value, otherwise true
    controlsFractionPrinting[i] = !usedMap.containsKey(count[i]);

    // now add the value to the map to signify it has been 'used'
    usedMap.add(count[i], null);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(controlsFractionPrinting));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
```

Comment: I thing you have a typo. It should be !usedMap.containsKey(count[i]) :p

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,1,3,3,2,2,2};
List<Integer> exists = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Boolean> result = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for(int i: arr){
    if(exists.contains(i)){
        result.add(false);
    } else {
        result.add(true);
        exists.add(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
```

Comment: I think it's Map.containsKey()